# How can we introduce ACID transactions for large files on CosmosDB

Tags: transactions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We have an application in which we have quite large documents which represent our domain. Multiple documents combined represent our aggregate root.

How can we ensure that the POST and PUT functionality can happen in an ACID way? Because of the limitation of 2MB per request to CosmosDB we cannot immediately find a way around it.

We want to prevent that, in case of an update of our documents (which are all in the same logical partition), when one save (post/put) fails our data reaches an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 0):

Transactional batch operations are supported in Azure Cosmos DB however the limitation is 2MB size per request which violates your scenario.

Another way is to use stored procedures to achieve Multi-Document Transactions, but again stored procedure are scoped to single partition key:

You can check this article to know more on it:

[Authoring Azure Cosmos DB Stored Procedures for Multi-Document Transactions](https://cosmosdb.github.io/labs/dotnet/labs/06-multi-document-transactions.html)